# How to setup vim/emacs keybindings in RStudio?

Tags: r, vim, emacs, key-bindings, rstudio

RStudio constantly requires taking fingers away from "asdf-jkl;" to the arrow keys. Not very comfortable after working with IPython's Emacs keybindings.

RStudio has vim navigation for file editing, but not for the console. (And that's not the real vim navigation. Some commands do not work at all.)

How can I setup a more friendly keyboard navigation Emacs/Vim-like for the console in RStudio?

Comment: "Software tools commonly used by programmers" are *on*-topic, people.

Comment: I love Rstudio and Vim, I'm really mourning the lose of predictable support for `move to`, `delete to`, etc. :-(

Answer (score 10):

You can turn vim keybindings of RStudio on in Tools | Global Options | Code | Editing, like this:

[image]
Please make sure your RStudio's version is above v0.99.x!

Answer (score 3):

On Macs, you can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app, which enables vi/vim/emacs keybindings everywhere, including RStudio. Karabiner is more flexible and functional than native Cocoa quasi-Emacs bindings.